# c# QueryString how to send data from one webpage to another?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, asp.net-mvc, string

I wanted to ask a little complicated question for me. I want to make a simple program like I have website [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) and there would be a simple panel to enter your name and your country. After that you have to click "send" and it will give you a request number like 12345. The data entered on that panel will be sent to the another site at wwww.example2.com . And I will check the data given from example1 to example2 (like: name: John , country : Jamaica , request number :12345) . I found on internet something like querystring at c# but im not sure what to do. I demand your help , best regards.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is possible you could navigate the browser from site [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) to [www.example2.com/someAction?name=joe](http://www.example2.com/someAction?name=joe) for example. However, in order to validate against this you would need some sort of server in which example1 would have to send the data first and store it. This would then allow example2 to call that service checking the data it got via query params was valid. This is a very long winded way to pass data about not sure it is a good solution.